# Date Time Difference in SQL 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, date-format

How to get date and time difference between `10/12/2010 07:35:02 PM` and `2010-11-19 21:51:01.713`. Where first date is in MM-DD-YYYY format and Second date is in YYYY-MM-DD Format Rest is time it is also in different format as first format has "pm" in it. Please let me know how to write a query in sql 08 to calculate date and time difference?

Answer (score 2):

The `datetime` data type in SQL Server is actually a 8-byte number. It may be represented in different formats to please humans but the format has no meaning to SQL Server itself.

To calculate the time difference between to `datetime` values you can use the built-in `DATEDIFF` function, which you can find details about here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

This will work thanks to the SQL Server ability to parse formatted dates for us:

```
select datediff(day, '10/12/2010 07:35:02 PM', '2010-11-19 21:51:01.713')
-----------
38
```

Comment: I had just SQLFiddled this same query. Here's the link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/21989